# How to get a value from a different sheet if two cells match in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to do something that would be simple in Excel, but in Google Sheets you have to use `INDIRECT` in a formula to get a value from a different sheet.

All I want to do is pull the value in Sheet1!B2 if Sheet1!A2 equals A2.

I tried it several ways, below are a couple

```
=IF(Sheet1!A2=A2),INDIRECT("Sheet1!B2")
```

and

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!B2")IF(Sheet1!A2=A2)
```

Answer (score 0):

> in Google Sheets you have to use INDIRECT in a formula to get a value from a different sheet

is not correct.

Try:

```
=if(A2=Sheet1!A2,Sheet1!B2,"")
```

If that does not return the content of Sheet1!B2 then A2 does not equal Sheet1!A2 (even if they look the same).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is the same result. Instead of showing the value Sheet1B2, it shows nothing, unless I put something in the final set of quotes you have.